# PySerial's readlines() consumes 25x times as much CPU time as read()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I'm reading a constant flow of data over a serial port, using pyserial:

```
import serial
s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', 9600)
```

If I'm using .read method, like this

```
while True:
    print(s.read(1000))
```

It consumes something around 1-2% CPU

But if I start getting them in a list, which is more convenient, like that

```
while True:
    print(s.readlines(1000))
```

CPU usage suddenly spikes up to 50%, which seems a bit unreasonable with only difference of output being split in the new lines.

Am I doing something wrong, is there a way to get readlines() method to use CPU more sparingly?

Thank you

Comment: Weird. I know `.readlines` rounds up to finish the current line it's on but surely that shouldn't cause this much of a difference. Does using `s.readline()` give the same kind of issue?

Comment: I have no explanation. Reads should be blocking unless `timeout=0`. `pyserial` has `.readuntil()`, does it make problems too? Link: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.read_until

Comment: @RolvApneseth Yes, readline() acts the same way readlines() does in this case.

Comment: @VPfB Yes, read_until() also eats 50% as it waits for newline

Comment: @Kasami I checked the source briefly. `read_until` calls `read(1)`. Strange that `read(1000)` is OK and `read(1)` is not. Maybe you should report the issue to the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `readlines` and `readline` busily poll the serial line for new characters in order to fulfill your request to get a full line (or lines), whereas `.read` will only read and return when there indeed is new data. You'll probably have to implement buffering and splitting to lines yourself (code untested since I don't have anything on a serial line right now :-) ):

```
import serial


def read_lines(s, sep=b"\n"):
    buffer = b""
    while True:
        buffer += s.read(1000)
        while sep in buffer:
            line, _, buffer = buffer.partition(sep)
            yield line


s = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyACM0", 9600)

for line in read_lines(s):
    print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you! This solution with buffering does work and takes 2-2.5% CPU, which is what I'd expect.
Very surprising it's not a part of pyserial!